# Javascipt fetch parse JSON result

Tags: javascript

```
let apiUrl = this.serverAdress + '/api2/auth-token/';

const data = {
  'username': this.username,
  'password': this.password
};
let header = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'X-SEAFILE-OTP': totp
};

const response = await fetch(new Request(apiUrl, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: new Headers(header),
  body: JSON.stringify(data),
}));

return response;
```

I am receiving a response from an API as follows, I want to parse the result as JSON.

When I try to access the token using `await response.json()["token"]` I get back undefined.

Comment: `const json = await fetch(...).then(response => response.json());` or `(await response.json())["token"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`response.json()` returns a promise that will resolve to the result of parsing the JSON.

Object accessors have higher precedence than `await` so your code is expecting  `response.json()["token"]` to be a promise.

```
const parsedResponse = await response.json();
const token = parsedResponse.token;
```

You could also use parentheses to control precedence, but the result isn't as readable.

```
const token = (await response.json()).token;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
(await response.json()).token
```